# How can I get my Tipper program done right?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing a Tipper program for the job, and I am having a lot of issues with it. The result keeps saying invalid syntax, and I have switched up so many things but it seems like I can never make it just right. To give you an example of this, here is my current code:

```
print("Now that your belly is full, how much is the fee?")
fee = input("Enter your fee: ")
print("Would you like to give us a tip?")
answer = input("Yes or no?")
if answer == no:
    why = input("Why do you not want to tip us? Also, you don't have to answer. When done, just press enter.")
    print("We understand. Here is your fee:", fee)
elif answer == yes:
    tip = input("Would you like to tip 15 percent or 20 percent? ")
    if tip == 15 :
        cost1 = fee/15 + fee
    elif tip == 20 :
            cost2 = fee/20 + fee
    else:
        print("I do not understand.")
else:
    print("I do not understand.")
print:("Have a wonderful day!")
```

So, yeah, to be honest with you I am not sure why it is not working, but could someone please answer? I am really stumped by this.

Comment: `if answer == no:`  ... you ment  `if answer == "no":` ?

Comment: `tip = input("Would you like to tip 15 percent or 20 percent? ") if tip == 15 :`  - tip is a string and NEVER 15 .

Comment: Why would I need to tilp 15 or 20 - maybe I just want to give 8% ... or a fixed amount ....

Comment: There are probably plenty of other bugs in it ... maybe you should learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before you produce production code

Comment: Ok so then what am I supposed to put between the 15 and tip?

Comment: Also, your tipping formula is wrong.  `fee / 20 + fee` will give a 5% tip.  You don't divide by the percentage, you multiply:  `cost = fee + fee * tip / 100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bugs in your code and tested it, however the overall code structure can still be improved.

So what caused your program to crash?

- "No" and "Yes" are both strings so you have to put them between " "
- You have to convert the fee entered from the user to integer using `int()` function so that you can do math calculations on it.
- You were calculating the tip wrongly, I fixed it using these calculations
  15% >> Total = 1.15xfee
  20% >> Total = 1.20xfee
  Note: in the below code I used the `math.ceil()` function to round up the tip to a whole number.
  To improve the user experience a bit, I also added a line that prints the total cost, including the tip, back to the user.
  Here is the corrected code:

```
import math

print("Now that your belly is full, how much is the fee?")
fee = int(input("Enter your fee: "))
print("Would you like to give us a tip?")
answer = input("yes or no?")
if answer == "no":
    why = input("Why do you not want to tip us? Also, you don't have to answer. When done, just press enter.")
    print("We understand. Here is your fee:", fee)
elif answer == "yes":
    tip = int(input("Would you like to tip 15 percent or 20 percent? "))
    if tip == 15 :
        cost = math.ceil(1.15 * fee)
        print("Your total, including fee is, ", cost)
    elif tip == 20 :
            cost = math.ceil(1.20 * fee)
            print("Your total, including fee is, ", cost)
    else:
        print("I do not understand.")
else:
    print("I do not understand.")
print("Have a wonderful day!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: You're welcome and best of luck to you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works.  Now, there are still problems.  First, it doesn't catch if they enter garbage that is not a number for the bill or for the tip.  Second, it doesn't round the tip, because I don't know what currency you're using.  But at least you can run this and get an answer.

```
print("Now that your belly is full, how much is the bill?")
fee = float(input("Enter your bill: "))
print("Would you like to give us a tip?")
answer = input("yes or no?")
if answer.lower() == 'no':
    why = input("Why do you not want to tip us? Also, you don't have to answer. When done, just press enter.")
    print("We understand.")
elif answer.lower() == "yes":
    tip = int(input("What tip percentage do you use? "))
    fee += fee * tip / 100
else:
    print("I do not understand.")
print("Your total bill is", fee)
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to wrap the answers you're testing for in quotes (double quotes `"`, or single quotes `'` will do), because otherwise python will think they are variable names and not string literals, that you want to compare against.

Also, in the last print, you have a colon (`:`) that doesn't belong there.

Here is your code with those two issues fixed.

```py
print("Now that your belly is full, how much is the fee?")
fee = input("Enter your fee: ")
print("Would you like to give us a tip?")
answer = input("Yes or no?")
if answer == 'no':
    why = input("Why do you not want to tip us? Also, you don't have to answer. When done, just press enter.")
    print("We understand. Here is your fee:", fee)
elif answer == 'yes':
    tip = input("Would you like to tip 15 percent or 20 percent? ")
    if tip == 15:
        cost1 = fee / 15 + fee
    elif tip == 20:
        cost2 = fee / 20 + fee
    else:
        print("I do not understand.")
else:
    print("I do not understand.")
print("Have a wonderful day!")
```

Also, this way of hard coding options and no easy way to skip questions (once answered 'yes' for example) makes for a ***very*** frustrating user experience, but that is another issue.

Edit:
You're also comparing strings to numbers, which will always be false, which saves you from the error, that trying to divide a string by a number would produce

Comment: Your code is still wrong.  `input` returns a string, so `tip` will never equal `15` or `20`, and `fee` is also a string.

Comment: you're right, I just saw that and wanted to come back to mention that ^^